# React.js - unable to get the specific prop from a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

so ,i have hard coded the state of the parent component and after passing it in the child component i am unable to retrieve it the child component.
and on the other hand if i pass any other other prop other than the state it works.

this is the child component:

```
import React from 'react';
import './searchresults.css'


class SearchResults extends React.Component {

render(){

 let searchresults=   this.props.searchresults;
    
        


return(
<div className= "searchresults">

<h2>Weather</h2>
<h3>Temprature:{searchresults.main.temp} </h3>
<h3>Temperature minimum: 25 degrees</h3>
<h3>Temperature maximum: 40 degrees</h3>
<h3>Humidity: 81% </h3>
</div>

)

}

}

export default SearchResults;
```

this is the parent component:

```
import React from 'react';

import './App.css';
import SearchBar from '../searchbar/searchbar'
import SearchResults from '../SearchResults/searchresults'

class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      searchresults:[{"coord":{"lon":-0.13,"lat":51.51},"weather":[{"id":300,"main":"Drizzle","description":"light intensity drizzle","icon":"09d"}],"base":"stations",
      "main":{"temp":280.32,"pressure":1012,"humidity":81,"temp_min":279.15,"temp_max":281.15
    },"visibility":10000,"wind":{"speed":4.1,"deg":80},"clouds":{"all":90},"dt":1485789600,"sys":{"type":1,"id":5091,"message":0.0103,"country":"GB","sunrise":1485762037,"sunset":1485794875},"id":2643743,"name":"London","cod":200}]
    }
  }

  render(){
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
       <h1>Wanderer</h1> 
      </header>
      <SearchBar />

      <SearchResults searchresults ={this.state.searchresults}
                        />
    </div>
  );
}
}

export default App;
```

and this the error i get:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'temp' of undefined
> SearchResults.render
> F:/rishit/wanderer/src/components/SearchResults/searchresults.js:18

Comment: The error tells you that `searchresults.main` is undefined. Use the tips in [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) to debug your code and figure out why.

Comment: Also, you can make your code easier for us to read and understand by following standard indentation conventions and not using so much whitespace that we have to scroll unnecessarily.

Answer (score 1):

Since `searchresults` in the parent with one item you could pass it like :

```
 <SearchResults searchresults ={this.state.searchresults[0]} />
```

Answer (score 1):

searchResults is an arrray it should be searchresults[0].main.temp

```
<h3>Temprature:{searchresults[0].main.temp} </h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, searchresults is an array. You need to provide index to access an element.
You can use searchresults[0].main.temp but that is not the best way and not a solution if searchresults had multiple elements. I would do it in the following way.

```
import React from 'react';
import './searchresults.css'


class SearchResults extends React.Component {

render(){
 return(
  this.props.searchresults.map((searchResult) => (
    <div className= "searchresults">
      <h2>Weather</h2>
      <h3>Temprature:{searchResult.main.temp}</h3>
      <h3>Temperature minimum: 25 degrees</h3>
      <h3>Temperature maximum: 40 degrees</h3>
      <h3>Humidity: 81% </h3>
    </div>
   ))  
  )
 }
}
```

I hope it works.